# None but the Heart is What matters

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Confined with my brothers

Occasionally I see Light

Sent to amuse others

For I don't have any life

Can't see because Eyes is what I don't have

Its the matter of hands but I lack that

God showed some Mercy by giving me heart

Make a guess and tell what we are.

Comment: Mixing "I" and "we" intentionally?

Comment: Its just that If I gave even a bit more info the answer will get quiet obvious @IanMacDonald

Comment: Sure, I just mean that in the last line you've switched to "we" where you had previously said "I" in the rest of the riddle. Should the "we" be changed to "I" for consistency, or is this intentional?

Comment: Intentional you can say.. Will wait for a while for someone to answer., If same thing happen with everyone I'll try to edit the same to something more convenient @IanMacDonald

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will guess that you are

> The Ace of Hearts in a deck of cards

Confined with my brothers

> A deck of cards is often kept in a closed cardboard packet

Occasionally I see Light

> Although if someone wishes to play a game, they take them out.

Sent to amuse others

> Cards are used to play games

For I don't have any life

> Cards are inanimate objects.

Can't see because Eyes is what I don't have

> Some cards could be said to have eyes but most don't, particularly the Ace of Hearts would not.

Its the matter of hands but I lack that

> Cards are dealt into hands but do not have hands.

God showed some Mercy by giving me heart

> The singular here makes me think that you are the Ace.

Make a guess and tell what we are.

> A deck of cards

Answer (score 0):

It could be/they could be  (partial one)

> A wisdom tooth/teeth

For,

> they are confined to mouth and occasionally see light when one speaks/laughs.

Also,

> They are shown when we try to amuse others by a giggle/smile.

And,

> they do the job of hands- hold/clasp though not as good as the hands.

Not sure about the

> *..have heart ...* part.

Comment: I started drafting this answer as well (not the specific item you're referring to, but the general 5-letter word), but realized that the 'heart' clue was very weak. I thought the pulp of an _*answer*_ could be treated as its heart... but rejected it as too weak.